# Getting stuck in this method  returning wrong value from table

Tags: android

```
 public int countGuestvisitnew() throws SQLException {
    Log.v("", " count when 1111 click = ");

    try {

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from guestvisitsnew", null);
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        int f=c.getCount();

            Log.v("", " count1212121 whenbus click =/// " + f);
            return f;


    } 
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Always getting count = 1,but there is no data in guestvisitsnew table.How can I get the row count from the table.
Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you inserting any value in this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(*) from guestvisitsnew
```

Will return 1 row, that contains the `count(*)`.

```
c.getCount()
```

will then return 1.

Change it to:

```
int f=c.getInt(0);
if (f > 0) {
    Log.v("", " count1212121 whenbus click =/// " + f);
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

count(number of rows) is 1 because you are trying to select count(*) which will return the number of rows

Change your code to

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from guestvisitsnew", null);
int noOfRows = c.getInt(0);
....
```